# Fast `Shallow` for Associations?

Tags: performance-tuning, output-formatting, output

`Shallow` does not seem to work with associations:

```
$r = ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}];
Shallow@$r

$r = Association["x" -> ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}]];
Shallow@$r
```

the second construction involves a large lag, probably by the kernel sending all that stuff to the FrontEnd which it will finally display in a "large  output" box.

Would you consider this a bug?

In the meantime, what options do we have for getting an overview over large expressions including Associations without incurring all that overhead?

---

WRI:

> Thank you for taking the time to send us this suggestion to extend the usefulness of Shallow to Associations. I have forwarded your suggestion to the appropriate people in our development group. I have also included your contact information so that you can be notified if this gets implemented.

Comment: I would consider it something worth reporting.

Comment: @Szabolcs done.

Answer (score 1):

```
$r = Association["x" -> ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}]];
    Shallow@($r /. Association -> Normal@*Association)
```

performs well.

Comment: `Shallow[y /. 
  x_Association :> {z = "Association" @@ Normal@Association@x}~
    With~(z /; True)]` preserves the information of which heads where `Association`

Answer (score 1):

This formats Associations in the usual way:

```
ShallowAssociation[x_Association] := 
  RawBoxes@(({s = Shallow@Normal@x}~With~MakeBoxes@s)~
     Replace~(RowBox[{"{", val_, "}"}] :> 
       RowBox@{"\[LeftAssociation]", val, "\[RightAssociation]"})
    );
```

Usage:

```
$c = ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}];
$c(*slow*)
Shallow@$c(*fast*)

$a = Association["x" -> ConstantArray[0, {1000, 1000}], "y" -> 0];
Shallow@$a(*slow*)
ShallowAssociation@$a(*fast*)

$ac = {$a, $c};
Shallow@$ac(*slow*)
Shallow@($ac /. x_Association :> ShallowAssociation@x)(*fast*)
```

So this is a more general and faster `Shallow`:

```
FastShallow[y_] := Shallow[y /. x_Association :> ShallowAssociation@x]
```

Comment: though MakeBoxes might be a bottleneck here with more complicated expressions